# Xpath locator to the same web element

Tags: xpath

I have one the same xpath for two elements on page. But I need to select first or second[image: xpath]
to anticipate the questions I can not use id because it is changing dynamically after new page starter.
also I tried use it as a list argument[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgwbO.png) and [0] but not working cos got only two arguments all together

```
('//input[@placeholder="Deeplink" and @class ="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"][1]')

[input#mat-input-13.mat-input-element.mat-form-field-autofill-control.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-va…, input#mat-input-19.mat-input-element.mat-form-field-autofill-control.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-va…]
```

Comment: can you find any other id on the section which is not changing

Comment: Can you post the actual html instead of an image?

Comment: @ShubjamJain I can't the placeholder is not changing but it is the same for both web element

Comment: @JackFleeting ```<input _ngcontent-c43="" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" matinput="" readonly="" id="mat-input-13" placeholder="Deeplink" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false">```

Comment: @ranger can you provide us input data as text, not as image?

Comment: @dafie I already did                                                                                                     ```<input _ngcontent-c36 class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" matinput="" readonly="" id="mat-input-12" placeholder="Deeplink" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false">```

Comment: like You see here id=mat input number is changing

Comment: [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).  It is likely, the question will be downvoted, for containing unnecessary screenshots.  By using screenshots, you are discouraging anyone from assisting you.  No one wants to retype your stuff, from a screenshot, and screenshots are often, not readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xpath to select first one use index 1

```
'(//input[@placeholder="Deeplink" and @class ="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"])[1]'
```

Xpath to select last one use `[last()]`

```
'(//input[@placeholder="Deeplink" and @class ="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"])[last()]'
```

Comment: ```'(//input[@placeholder="Deeplink" and @class ="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"])[1]``` its not working cos when use [1] both lists are mentioned

Comment: the second answer was ok ' [last()] ' make a good work but if I want to select first list what parameter should typed here ? [ ????? ()]

Comment: @ranger : it is very difficult to provide  perfect answer based on screenshot.It would be great if you post your DOM in text format .

Answer (score 0):

You can try:`//input[contains(@id,'mat-input-')]`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24347341)

Comment: @IgorF. Like any xpath solution can become invalid if the linked page changes.